# Laravel Add Loader while submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Currently I am doing laravel and my submit somehow takes a long time loading (for like 5 seconds) because I am sending an email

I would like to add a loader while its still submitting just like in ajax, but I am not using ajax for this. I used a form submit here

**index.blade.php**

```
 <form  id="form-contact" name="form-contact" action="{{route('inquiries.submit')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        // some fields
 </form>
```

**Route**

```
  Route::post('/contact/inquiries', 'ApiController@contactForm')->name('inquiries.submit');
```

**Controller**

```
public function contactForm(Request $request)
{

    $data['fname'] = $request->fname;
    $data['lname'] = $request->lname;
    $data['body'] = $request->body;
    $data['recipient_email'] = $request->email;
    $data['type'] = 'Inquiry';

      //some email sending code

    Session::put('inquirySuccess', 'Task successfully added!');
    $this->emailSent->create($data);
    return redirect()->back();

}
```

**inquiry.js**

```
angular.module('app').controller('inquiryController', function($scope, $http, $window) {


    if ($('#inquiry-success').length) {

        swal({
            title: "Inquiry Sent!",
            text: "",
            type: "success",
            showCancelButton: false,
            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            confirmButtonText: 'OK',
        })

    }


});
```

How do I add loader while until the submission is completed? I am using laravel 1.4

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do that without ajax call. Because if you submit a form, you are gone from the current page. So make the form submission Ajaxify and show a loader until you get a response from server.